# How to add parenthesis around on series field in incollection type of references in BST File

Tags: bibtex

I am very new to BST file editing. Any one could please try to give a solution on this one.

BST Coding:

```
FUNCTION {format.series}
{ series empty$ 
   { "" }
   { this.to.prev.status
     this.status.std 
     bbl.series  "(" * pop$  *
     series "series" bibinfo.check ")" *
     cap.status.std
   }
 if$
}
```

INPUT:

```
\bibinfo{series}{Tribology Series}
```

Expected OUTPUT:

```
(\bibinfo{series}{Tribology Series})
```

Comment: Can you tell us where this comes from? Some of the functions here are non-standard (not from the 'core' BibTeX set) so it's hard to know exactly what is on the stack and what is happening.

Comment: @JosephWright: It is from bib file to bbl conversion using IEEE bst file. And I need to update the series field with around parenthesis for "incollection" type of references. I am very very new for this platform. And I tried and got it (may be the coding will not be proper what I edited and anyway output got with expected). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I got it:

```
FUNCTION {format.series}
{ series empty$ 
   { "" }
   { this.to.prev.status
     this.status.std
      ", (" *
     series "series" bibinfo.check *  ")" *
     cap.status.std
   }
 if$
}
```